# How to mount Soft RAID in centOS

Tags: centos, mount, software-raid

My dedicated server crashes. I've rebooted it in rescue mode and want to mount to see the log and/or fix the boot file.

I've CentOS and soft RAID. How do I mount soft RAID?
Following are the details:

```
root@rescue:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty]
md2 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      20478912 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md3 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      1932506048 blocks [2/2] [UU]
      [===>.................]  resync = 15.3% (296176384/1932506048) finish=231.8min speed=117626K/sec

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: what "boot file" you want to fix?

Answer (score 1):

You've got two RAID's (md2 and md3). You can use `mdadm -D /dev/md2` and `mdadm -D /dev/md3` to get more info.

Mounting is very easy: e.g. `mount /dev/md2 /mnt/dir`.
You should refer to `/etc/fstab` file on how your RAID storages were mounted normally.